# R: Sending only a column of Data Frame (not the data frame) to a user defined function

Tags: r

I know very similar questions have been asked before but I still haven't got the answer to my exact question from those older posts. My function 'test' needs to perform **only** on a column 'col' of a data-frame (actually data from a .csv file) 'x' i.e.

```
test <- function(x$col){...}
:
test(x$col)
```

I know this syntax doesn't work. So I need to do:

```
test <- function(x,col){...}
:
test(x$col)
```

But the problem with the above is, since R functions inherently pass by value, the entire dataframe 'x' gets passed on to the function 'test' which is a highly in-efficient way, esp with a LARGE 'x'!

A work-around is:

```
test <- function(y){...}
:
y <- x$col
test(y)
```

But this is not good. I add an-extra-line-of-code/vector for a weird phenomenon for which I see no obvious reason! Also, this complicates the readability of the code since everywhere else in the code I use `x$col` for that column.

Is there a way to send just a copy of the column (`x$col`) by using some combination of 'x' and 'col' (and no extra variable!) as an argument to my function 'test'??

Or can someone please suggest a reason for not being able to send just a column as an argument to the function 'test'? Also, is it generally inefficient to use `x$col` each time since it may not be in the memory all the time?

Comment: Can you test/confirm that passing the full data frame and then extracting a column is **actually** inefficient? R does some moderately clever stuff to try *not* to make copies unless it's necessary.  The best reference I can find for this on short notice is section 1.1.2  of http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html

Comment: Passing the whole data.frame isn't as inefficient as it looks as because R is copy-on-write; R Internals has more info, though it's fairly technical. http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#Rest-of-header.  It does seem to me that @PaulHiemstra's answer is what you're looking for though.

Comment: @BenBolker: I believe you are correct; I actually found the same reference.  I used to think the same as the OP and for one complex function actually tried rewriting with environments, thinking that it would avoid copying the data; when it didn't speed up at all I read up on R's copy-on-write methods.

Comment: Actually, @Aditi, your second syntax won't work either; it would need to be `function(x, col) test(x[[col]])`.

Comment: I agree with Ben and Aaron: don't worry, you are not copying the whole dataset.

Comment: Thanks everyone! My reason of thinking that the entire data frame is passed on was, if i invoked summary(dataframe) from within the function, it would give me the summary of the entire dataframe.  However I did not find the reference on copy-on-write then! I think you all are right! Thanks for the knowledge sharing. I am a newbie to R and so these small and silly questions every now and then!

Comment: This has to do with scoping. You see the original object in the global env, not a copy inside the function. This kind of scoping can be both convinient and a pain.

Comment: Did one of the answers help you? Could you tick that as the correct answer?

Comment: You have not selected an answer as the correct one (as you have not done for any of your questions). If we help you through stackoverflow, please tick the answer you thought was the right answer. In this way the community knows that the question has been answered, and the answerer gets some reputation.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't this just work:

```
spam <- function(col) {
   return(col*10)
}

dat <- data.frame(bla = 1:10, xi = 1:10)

spam(dat$bla)
```

I do not think that `bla` is passed on in its entirety to the function. Looking at:

```
> str(dat$bla)
 int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I suspect that a new object is created when sub setting and that only the values in `dat$bla` are passed on. Or am I totally wrong here?

Comment: Thanks..this technique works! However, my reason of concluding that the entire data frame is passed on was, if i invoked summary(dat) from within the function spam, it would give me the summary of the entire data frame dat. You may want to try this. Thanks once again for the reply!

Comment: This probably has to do with the scoping that R uses. The object is not actually passed on into the function, but when R can't find dat inside the function, it will look in the global environment. so you are not looking at a copy inside spam, but at the original object in the global environment.

Answer (score 2):

It is going to depend on how you invoke test but any of these may be the answer:

```
test <- function(x,col){  x[[col]] } # for x being data.frame or list

test <- function(x,col){ x[ , col] } # for x being data.frame or matrix
```

You should avoid using the "$" operator  when passing arguments to functions because it does not convert the value of "col" to something else. It tries to return a column by the name of "col" and that is generally NOT what you wnat when you pass an argument to a function. The "[" and "[[" functions on the other hand will evaluate `col` and do the extraction with the value of what you passed.

If you want to work on only a single column then this is also a possibility:

```
test <- with(x, function(col) {col} )  
# obviously you could do more with col inside the braces
```

The `with` function sets up an environment where "col" will be interpreted as a valid object name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Passing $ gives an error...so it cannot be passed as an argument to the function, whether avoidable or not. Passing (x,col) passes the entire x to the function. I may be wrong but I concluded this based on the observation that if i invoked summary(x) from within the function spam, it would give me the summary of the entire data frame x.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but is this waht you want?

```
#Your Data Frame
x<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5))
x

#A Function to text Something, you choose the data and the columm
test.function<- function(data.frame,columm) {
                                            data.frame[,columm]>0
                                            }
#Work either with the number of the columm                                            
test.function(x,1)
#or de "name" of the columm
test.function(x,"X1")
```

Comment: I am sorry...I wanted a work-around this for the code's readability! Thanks for trying to help though :)